# Unable to render the html tags dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am using innerHTML property to insert a span into a div. But the span is not getting displayed immediately on the page. however if we use alert function immeditely after the innerHTML statement, the span is getting displayed. Please help
Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Robin

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code.

Comment: Also let us know: if you wait some time (without alert) does the `span` appear? If so after how much time?

Answer (score 1):

Try using DOM method:

```
// Create the span
var span = document.createElement('span');

//set attributes you want
span.setAttribute('id','mySpanId');

//Then append as child of the div you want
document.getElementById('myDivContainer').appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. 
I have tried the DOM method also But still no luck.
Please find below the code i used for DOM:
var progDiv = document.getElementById("mainProgDiv");
var progSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
progSpan.id = "progressSpan";
progSpan.className = "progSpanClass";
var progImage = document.createElement("IMG");
progImage.id = "progImg";
progImage.src = "Processing.gif";
progImage.className = "progImageClass";
progSpan.appendChild(progImage);
progDiv.appendChild(progSpan);

Am I missing something?

Comment: well it worked for me but i would like to ask where u put that code is it just in the javascript i mean u may call it before the DOM is ready .
any way i tried your code between window.onload=function(){//you code here }